# importing a csv file to oracle database

Tags: oracle, csv, sql-loader

I want to import a .csv file into an oracle database table below, but its not working and the log file is empty without no output.

my shell script is below:

and also the logfile is always empty

below is a sample of the .csv file

```
SendingFri,LoggingTime,RenewalNumber,TransactionType,Status,Duration
22997186945,2023-07-25-00:05:56.301,23900032093333,Payment,SUCCESS,null
22951547347,2023-07-25-00:04:12.794,23900336289912,Payment,SUCCESS,null
```

```
#!/bin/bash

# Oracle Database Connection Details
USERNAME='abc'
PASSWORD="abc"
HOST="myip"
PORT="1521"
SERVICE_NAME="abc"

# CSV File Details
CSV_FILE="/home/hdegboevi/modified5.csv"
TABLE_NAME="myCANALINFORMATION"

# Control File
CONTROL_FILE="my_control_file.ctl"

# Create a control file
cat <<EOF > $CONTROL_FILE
LOAD DATA
INFILE '$CSV_FILE'
APPEND INTO TABLE $TABLE_NAME
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
SENDINGFRI,
LOGGINGTIME,
RENEWALNUMBER,
TRANSACTIONTYPE,
STATUS,
DURATON
)
EOF

# Run SQL*Loader
sqlldr $USERNAME/$PASSWORD@$HOST:$PORT/$SERVICE_NAME control=$CONTROL_FILE log=/home/hdegboevi/sqlldr.log  /home/hdegboevi

# Check the log for errors
if grep "ORA-" sqlldr.log; then
    echo "Error occurred during data load. Please check sqlldr.log for details."
else
    echo "Data loaded successfully."
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have posted target table description; without it, we have to *guess* datatypes. My lucky guess (according to sample data):

```
SQL> desc test
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 SENDINGFRI                                         NUMBER
 LOGGINGTIME                                        TIMESTAMP(6)
 RENEWALNUMBER                                      NUMBER
 TRANSACTIONTYPE                                    VARCHAR2(20)
 STATUS                                             VARCHAR2(10)
 DURATION                                           VARCHAR2(20)

SQL>
```

which is probably wrong; `duration` column sounds as if you'd want to put e.g. a number in it (*something took 2 seconds to complete*), but sample data suggests that you're inserting a **string** into it (`null`, in this context, is a string).

With a control file you wrote, result is (in my database)

```
Record 1: Rejected - Error on table TEST, column LOGGINGTIME.
ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

---

Control file, fixed:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE *
REPLACE
INTO TABLE test
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
SENDINGFRI,
LOGGINGTIME "to_timestamp(:loggingtime, 'yyyy-mm-dd-hh24:mi:ss.ff')",
RENEWALNUMBER,
TRANSACTIONTYPE,
STATUS,
DURATION
)

begindata
22997186945,2023-07-25-00:05:56.301,23900032093333,Payment,SUCCESS,null
22951547347,2023-07-25-00:04:12.794,23900336289912,Payment,SUCCESS,null
```

Loading session:

```
SQL> $sqlldr scott/tiger@orcl control=test49.ctl log=test49.log

SQL*Loader: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Čet Kol 17 14:23:09 2023
Version 18.5.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Path used:      Conventional
Commit point reached - logical record count 1
Commit point reached - logical record count 2

Table TEST:
  2 Rows successfully loaded.

Check the log file:
  test49.log
for more information about the load.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from test;

   SENDINGFRI LOGGINGTIME                  RENEWALNUMBER TRANSACTIONTYPE      STATUS     DURATION
------------- ------------------------- ---------------- -------------------- ---------- --------------------
  22997186945 25.07.23 00:05:56,301000    23900032093333 Payment              SUCCESS    null
  22951547347 25.07.23 00:04:12,794000    23900336289912 Payment              SUCCESS    null

SQL>
```

---

OK; data is here.

I'd suggest you to first make that part of job correctly (i.e. loading itself), and then create a shell script. I can't assist about that, I don't use any kind of Unix operating systems.

---

**[EDIT, after you posted table description]**

Aha; so all columns are `varchar2`. Even simpler.

```
SQL> desc test
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 SENDINGFRI                                         VARCHAR2(30)
 LOGGINGTIME                                        VARCHAR2(30)
 RENEWALNUMBER                                      VARCHAR2(30)
 TRANSACTIONTYPE                                    VARCHAR2(30)
 STATUS                                             VARCHAR2(30)
 DURATON                                            VARCHAR2(30)

SQL>
```

(I thought it was a typo, "duraton" vs. "duration"; looks like it really is "duraton", whatever that might be).

Control file is trivial:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE *
REPLACE
INTO TABLE test
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
SENDINGFRI,
LOGGINGTIME,
RENEWALNUMBER,
TRANSACTIONTYPE,
STATUS,
DURATON
)

begindata
22997186945,2023-07-25-00:05:56.301,23900032093333,Payment,SUCCESS,null
22951547347,2023-07-25-00:04:12.794,23900336289912,Payment,SUCCESS,null
```

Loading session:

```
SQL> $sqlldr scott/tiger@orcl control=test49a.ctl log=test49a.log

SQL*Loader: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Čet Kol 17 14:48:15 2023
Version 18.5.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Path used:      Conventional
Commit point reached - logical record count 1
Commit point reached - logical record count 2

Table TEST:
  2 Rows successfully loaded.

Check the log file:
  test49a.log
for more information about the load.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from test;

SENDINGFRI   LOGGINGTIME               RENEWALNUMBER   TRANSACTIONTYPE STATUS     DURATON
------------ ------------------------- --------------- --------------- ---------- ----------
22997186945  2023-07-25-00:05:56.301   23900032093333  Payment         SUCCESS    null
22951547347  2023-07-25-00:04:12.794   23900336289912  Payment         SUCCESS    null

SQL>
```

Comment: this was the table------ SENDINGFRI       VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
  LOGGINGTIME      VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
  RENEWALNUMBER    VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
  TRANSACTIONTYPE  VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
  STATUS           VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
  DURATON          VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)

Comment: That's trivial, then. See edited answer, please.

Comment: Hello Thanks, so much but please is there are way to replay the begindata session with an csv file?

Comment: ok thanks its fine i just replace the * after the infile with the csv file

Comment: Yes, that's it; I used sample data within the control file (for simplicity). You did it right!